# php artisan doesnt work [ErrorException] Undefined offset: 0 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

when i try to run `php artisan` i give the error

```
 [Error Exception]     
 Undefined offset: 0
```

when i run `composer install` or `composer update` i got this error

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:
```

i install all extensions, run `composer dumpautoload` but i still get this error. the problem is in this current procjet(i created another laravel project and it works fine)

Comment: i cant think of any answer, how about replacing your artisan with a new one and update your composer

Comment: thanks for reply. i've already updated composer, could you please tell me how can i replace artisan witha new one?

Comment: just copy and past an artisan from a laravel project with the version as yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found out that in service provider, in boot method, there was db query which returned false, so array(where i put db query result) with index 0 doesnt exist

```
$result[0]->title // <---doesnt exist($result is empty)
```